# Issue with locks opening on both sides

Tags: doors, lock

I got a lot of locks for a new hotel (bungalows), and I want to make one side of the locks inaccessible to any key.  (They have 3 doors so only one needs a key for both sides).   Is there some way to make the exterior lock hole to not work but allow people to unlock from inside?

Comment: As we can't see what type of locks you mean, we can't say. Pictures always help.

Comment: This is a confusing question: are you actually proposing to have doors that lock people inside where they need a key to get out? Have you looked into fire/egress regulations in your area?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, I  think its the reverse. Howvever, its also offtopic because its not a home but a motel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "Killer Key" to permanently block the key slot. Either buy one or cut your own as shown below. Once you insert the key, the deep square cut catches on the pins and it can not be removed. Snap off the key at the weakened point and you're done.

[image: e]

[Photo credit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ABV7IIA)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is simply use a deadbolt...

Comment: I dont the Op is looking to replace that many locks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you're looking for a single sided deadbolt.  It has a knob to lock or unlock on one side and nothing on the other.  [Here's a link to an example](https://www.directdoorhardware.com/single-side-deadbolts.htm#:%7E:text=With%20single%2Dsided%20deadbolts%2C%20you,don%27t%20see%20the%20deadbolt.).  Many others can be found by searching for "single sided deadbolt" or "one sided deadbolt".